# Socket.IO via tor node.js

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, tor, socks

Suppose I have 2 servers. I want to establish a connection between them using socket.io library, and one of them would reach another by .onion link using SOCKS proxy. all the traffic between servers should also go through tor.
I was able to create a simple net socket using onion links, but cannot find how to pass it to socket.io. Is it possible to make socket.io using existing net socket? or maybe there is another way to achieve the ultimate goal?

Comment: How do you want the client to connect, from browser or `nodejs` binary on another server?

Comment: I have 2 servers both running tor routers on localhost (not tor browser). I want server 1 establish websocket connection to server 2 using .onion link. So far I was able to achieve it with net TCP and WebSocket, but not with socket.io.

Comment: The server acting as a client should be able to make the connection by running it through the `torsocks` command.  Like `torsocks nodejs client.js` where client.js has a call like `var socket = io.connect('http://youraddress.onion');`

Answer (score 0):

I have some working experiences with socket.io, but not with the other technologies you mention (so I can't resolve your question entirely). Until someone else resolves it, I will show you a link with about the two modules socket.io-redis and socket.io-emitter that allow socket.io to communicate with the "outside world":

https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#sending-messages-from-the-outside-world